# gnome-terminal and some other commands cannot start in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, shared-library

In Ubuntu 18.04 after some time of usage, I got the following error when trying to start **gnome-terminal**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
File "/home/victor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
from . import _gi
ImportError: /home/victor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: g_interface_info_find_method
```

Similar error occurs also when I try to launch **gnome-tweaks** or execute the command **add-apt-repository**.
However, when I try to run gnome-terminal from "open in terminal" menu of nautilus, it started normally.
The same error occurs also if I try to do in python3:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
```

I will be grateful for any advice.

Here is an additional output related to python3 parameters:

```
$ type python3; readlink /usr/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
python3.6
$ echo "$PYTHONPATH"; python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'

['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/victor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Finally, I have found the cause of error. The library **_gi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so** of python3.6 module **gi** depends on **libgirepository-1.0.so** from **libgirepository1.0-dev** package, but that dependence is not listed in the ELF header of the library. So, the workaround I have used is to add

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgirepository-1.0.so
```

to **~/.profile**. However, I still don't understand, how may that happen and how to solve the problem in the right way. I am a novice in C programming and have found the solution after reading the excellent paper on library linking at http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/

Comment: Please post the output of `type python3; readlink /usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: And post the output of `echo "$PYTHONPATH"; python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`

Comment: @wjandrea: Please, see the output in the edited post